# _shutdown AttributeError (ignored) when linting code that uses M2Crypto

Tags: python, m2crypto, pylint

I'm running lint as follows:

```
$ python -m pylint.lint m2test.py
```

with this code:

```
import M2Crypto
def f():
    M2Crypto.RSA.new_pub_key("").as_pem(cipher=None).split("\n")
```

The lint output ends with:

```
Exception AttributeError: '_shutdown' in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/M2Crypto/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

This code works fine when run (the above is actually a minimal test case; but the full version does work).  The exception is ignored, but [Bitten](http://bitten.edgewall.com) considers this a failure, so stops on this step.

I've tried adding 'M2Crypto.threading.init()'/'M2Crypto.threading.cleanup()' around the definition of the function, but that didn't fix the problem.

How can I prevent this problem from occurring?

I'm using M2Crypto 0.21.1, pylint 0.24 and Python 2.7 (also tried 2.7.2) on Debian Lenny x86_64.

Comment: I can reproduce it with `M2Crypto==0.21.1` and `pylint==0.24.0` on Linux x86_64.

Comment: @J.F. thanks for the prompt - I ought to have included versions originally.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 16):

The exception that you are seeing is caused by a bug in the `astng` package (presumably “Abstract Syntax Tree, Next Generation”?) which is a toolkit on which `pylint` depends, written by the same people. I should note in passing that I always encourage people to use `pyflakes` instead of `pylint` when possible, because it is quick, simple, fast, and predictable, whereas `pylint` tries to do several kinds of deep magic that are not only slow but that can get it into exactly this kind of trouble. :)

Here are the two packages on PyPI:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/astng

And note that this problem had to be, necessarily, a bug in `pylint` and *not* in your code, because `pylint` does *not* run your code in order to produce its report — imagine the havoc that could be wreaked if it did (since code being linted might delete files, etcetera)! Since your code does not get run, no amount of caution, like protecting your call with threading `init()` or `cleanup()` functions, could possibly have prevented this error — unless the code snippets happened, for other reasons, to alter the behavior we are about to investigate.

So, on to your actual exception.

I had never actually heard of `_shutdown` before! A quick search of the Python standard library showed its definition in `threading.py` but not a call of the function from anywhere; only by searching the Python C source code did I discover where in `pythonrun.c`, during interpreter shutdown, the function is actually called:

```
static void
wait_for_thread_shutdown(void)
{
    ...
    PyObject *threading = PyMapping_GetItemString(tstate->interp->modules,
                                                  "threading");
    if (threading == NULL) {
        /* threading not imported */
        PyErr_Clear();
        return;
    }
    result = PyObject_CallMethod(threading, "_shutdown", "");
    if (result == NULL) {
        PyErr_WriteUnraisable(threading);
    }
    ...
}
```

Apparently it is some sort of cleanup function that the `threading` Standard Library module requires, and they have special-cased the Python interpreter itself to make sure that it gets called.

As you can see from the code above, Python quietly and without complaint handles the case where the `threading` module never gets imported during a program's run. But if `threading` does get imported, and still exists at shutdown time, then the interpreter looks inside for a `_shutdown` function and goes so far as to print an error message — and then return a non-zero exit status, the cause of your problems — if it cannot call it.

So we have to discover why the `threading` module exists but has no `_shutdown` method at the moment when `pylint` is done examining your program and Python is exiting. Some instrumention is called for. Can we print out what the module looks like as `pylint` exits? We can! The `pylint/lint.py` module, in its last few lines, runs its “main program” by instantiating a `Run` class it has defined:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Run(sys.argv[1:])
```

So I opened `lint.py` in my editor — one of the magnificent things about having each little project installed in a Python Virual Environment is that I can jump in and edit third-party code for quick experiments — and added the following `print` statement down at the bottom of the `Run` class's `__init__()` method:

```
    sys.path.pop(0)
    print "*****", sys.modules['threading'].__file__  # added by me!
    if exit:
        sys.exit(self.linter.msg_status)
```

I re-ran the command:

```
python -m pylint.lint m2test.py
```

And out came the `__file__` string of the `threading` module:

```
***** /home/brandon/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/threading.pyc
```

Well, look at that.

**This is the problem!**

According to this path, there actually exists an `M2Crypto/threading.py` module that, under all normal circumstances, should just be called `M2Crypto.threading`, and therefore sit in the `sys.modules` dictionary under the name:

```
sys.modules['M2Crypto.threading']
```

But somehow that file is *also* getting loaded as the main Python `threading` module, shadowing the official `threading` module that sits in the Standard Library. Because of this, the Python exit logic is quite correctly complaining that the Standard Library `_shutdown()` function is missing.

How could this happen? Top-level modules can only appear in paths that are listed explicitly in `sys.path`, not in sub-directories beneath them. This leads to a new question: is there any point during the `pylint` run that the `…/M2Crypto/` directory itself is getting put on `sys.path` as though it contained top-level modules? Let's see!

We need more instrumentation: we need to have Python tell us the moment that a directory with `M2Crypto` in the name appears in `sys.path`. It will really slow things down, but let's add a trace function to pylint's `__init__.py` — because that is the first module that gets imported when you run `-m pylint.lint` — that will write an output file telling us, for every line of code executed, whether `sys.path` has any bad values in it:

```
def install_tracer():
    import sys
    output = open('mytracer.out', 'w')
    def mytracer(frame, event, arg):
        broken = any(p.endswith('M2Crypto') for p in sys.path)
        output.write('{} {}:{} {}\n'.format(
                broken, frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_lineno, event))
        return mytracer
    sys.settrace(mytracer)

install_tracer()
del install_tracer
```

Note how careful I am here: I define only one name in the module's namespace, and then carefully delete it to clean up after myself before I let `pylint` continue loading! And all of the resources that the trace function itself needs — namely, the `sys` module and the `output` open file — are available in the `install_tracer()` closure so that, from the outside, `pylint` looks exactly the same as always. Just in case anyone tries to introspect it, like `pylint` might!

This generates a file `mytracer.out` of about 800k lines, that each look something like this:

```
False /home/brandon/venv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py:118 call
```

The `False` says that `sys.path` looks clean, the filename and line number are the line of code being executed, and `call` indicates what stage of execution the interpreter is in.

So does `sys.path` ever get poisoned? Let's look at just the first `True` or `False` on each line, and see how many successive lines start with each value:

```
$ awk '{print$1}' mytracer.out | uniq -c
 607997 False
   3173 True
   4558 False
  33217 True
   4304 False
  41699 True
   2953 False
 110503 True
  52575 False
```

Wow! That's a problem! For runs of several thousand lines at a time, our test case is `True`, which means that the interpreter is running with `…/M2Crypto/` — or some variant of a pathname with `M2Crypto` in it — on the path, where it should not be; only the directory that *contains* `…/M2Crypto` should ever be on the path. Looking for the first `False` to `True` transition in the file, I see this:

```
False /home/brandon/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logilab/astng/builder.py:132 line
False /home/brandon/venv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py:118 call
...
False /home/brandon/venv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py:124 line
False /home/brandon/venv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py:124 return
True /home/brandon/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logilab/astng/builder.py:133 line
```

And looking at lines 132 and 133 in the `builder.py` file reveals our culprit:

```
130    # build astng representation
131    try:
132        sys.path.insert(0, dirname(path)) # XXX (syt) iirk
133        node = self.string_build(data, modname, path)
134    finally:
135        sys.path.pop(0)
```

Note the comment, which is part of the original code, not an addition of my own! Obviously, `XXX (syt) iirk` is an exclamation in this programmer's strange native language for the phrase, “put this module's parent directory on `sys.path` so that `pylint` will break mysteriously every time someone forces `pylint` to introspect a package with a `threading` sub-module.” It is, obviously, a very compact native language. :)

If you adjust the tracing module to watch `sys.modules` for the actual import of `threading` — an exercise I will leave to the reader — you will see that it happens when `SocketServer`, which is imported by some other Standard Library module during the analysis, in turn tries to innocently import `threading`.

So let us review what is happening:

1. `pylint` is dangerous magic.
2. As part of its magic, if it sees you `import foo`, then it runs off trying to find `foo.py` on disk, to parse it, and to predict whether you are loading valid or invalid names from its namespace.
3. [See my comment, below.] Because you call `.split()` on the return value of `RSA.as_pem()`, `pylint` tries to introspect the `as_pem()` method, which in turn uses the `M2Crypto.BIO` module, which in turn makes calls that induce `pylint` to import `threading`.
4. As part of loading any module `foo.py`, `pylint` throws the directory containing `foo.py` on `sys.path`, **even if that directory is inside a package**, and therefore gives modules in that directory the privilege of shadowing Standard Library modules of the same name during its analysis.
5. When Python exits, it is upset that the `M2Crypto.threading` library is sitting where `threading` belongs, because it wants to run the `_shutdown()` method of `threading`.

You should report this as a bug to the `pylint` / `astng` folks at `logilab.org`. Tell them I sent you.

If you decide to keep using `pylint` after it has done this to you, then there seem to be two solutions in this case: either don't inspect code that calls `M2Crypto`, or import `threading` during the `pylint` import process — by sticking `import threading` into the `pylint/__init__.py`, for example — so that the module gets the chance to grab the `sys.modules['threading']` slot *before* `pylint` gets all excited and tries to let `M2Crypto/threading.py` grab the slot instead.

In conclusion, I think the author of `astng` says it best: XXX (syt) iirk. Indeed.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks!  Your suggestion of inserting "import threading" prior to the M2Crypto import doesn't work, BTW.  I'm still a little unclear about some things: why, for example, does the error go away if I remove the .split()?  Some part of the dangerous pylint magic I suppose.  I'll look into this a bit more tomorrow when I have time, and open a ticket for it at logilab.  I'm pretty sure the bounty is yours :)

Comment: Thank you, @Tony Meyer! Both for the compliment, and for pointing out that I got the recommendation wrong at the end: I meant to say, add `import threading` to `pylint`, not to the sample code! I have now fixed the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Tony Meyer — to answer your other question, run `pylint` inside of `strace -o trace.out` and then use `grep 'open.*py.*= [^-]'` on the resulting trace to see what Python modules are imported in each case. You will see that when you add `split()`, `pylint` decides to introspect the `as_pem()` method because it now wants to verify its return type. To introspect `as_pem()` it needs to import `BIO.py`, which otherwise it would ignore, and that leads to a cascade of 40+ additional imports that eventually reach `M2Crypto.threading`.

Comment: Wow.  Most thorough answer I have seen to date.  I think I'll try `pyflakes`.

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to Brandon Craig Rhodes for having tracing this down and for such a detailed post.

I've removed the offending line from astng, code available from the [hg repository](http://hg.logilab.org/logilab/astng) until logilab-astng 0.23.0 is out. And I can confirm this fixes the OP's pb.

Comment: Wonderful! I am glad to have been of help to your project. :) If the line can simply be removed, does that mean that whatever original purpose it had is gone now? And, the big question: do the project owners themselves know what the author of that line really meant by “XXX (syt) iirk”? I keep wondering what it stood for!

Comment: @Brandon: yes, the original purpose is gone, that was a quick and dirty fix regarding relative import that has been properly fixed later by changing other api so the "context file" (ie module from which the import is done) may be given. The "XXX (syt) iirk" means : "easy to find later note about some pb / quick & dirty fix" (XXX) "by me" (syt) "this stinks" (iirk) :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a hack but I think it works. Copying the result of "as_pem()" and splitting it.

```
import M2Crypto
def f():
    M2Crypto.RSA.new_pub_key("").as_pem(cipher=None)[:].split("\n")
```

I'm using Python 2.6.7, M2Crypto 0.21.1, pylint 0.23

Comment: The code's not doing the same thing - you're splitting t, whereas the original splits t.as_pem(cipher=None).  Split into separate lines in that case, it still generates the error.

Comment: Curiously, if I copy the result of t.as_pem(cipher=None) to another variable and split by new lines it works (m = t.as_pem(cipher=None)[:].split("\n"))

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce (pylint 0.24 and M2Crypto 0.21.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 64bit) but two suggestions:

Explicitly initialize threading:

```
import M2Crypto
def f(): 
    M2Crypto.threading.init()
    M2Crypto.RSA.new_pub_key("").as_pem(cipher=None).split("\n")
    M2Crypto.threading.cleanup()
```

Or recompile without threading:

```
m2crypto = Extension(name = 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto',
                 sources = ['SWIG/_m2crypto.i'],
                 extra_compile_args = ['-DTHREADING'],
                 #extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-search_paths_first'], # Uncomment to build Universal Mac binaries
                 )
```

Comment: As in the question, I did try explicitly initialising threading - it seemed the most likely culprit.  I'll try rebuilding M2Crypto when I get a chance.

Comment: That you can't reproduce is interesting.  What version of Python did you try with?

Comment: init()/cleanup() do not help. I've tried Python 2.6/2.7 M2Crypto 0.20.1/0.21.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 64bit